Multiple inputs to subprocess.Popen
I have a program which requires 2 inputs to be passed.
How to achieve it using subprocess
import subprocess

pass1 = "welcome1"
pass2 = "welcome2"

session = subprocess.Popen("sh", "test.sh", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = session.communicate(pass1.encode('utf-8'))
stdout, stderr = session.communicate(pass2.encode('utf-8'))

Now I am unable to provide pass2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/roman/temp/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    stdout, stderr = session.communicate(pass2.encode('utf-8'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1129, in communicate
    raise ValueError("Cannot send input after starting communication")
ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication


Take a look at subprocess.run() which is the preferred technique unless you need particular features offered by the lower-level Popen

Unless the subprocess is timing-sensitive, just join the two with a newline.
As pointed out elsewhere (including in the Popen documentation), you should prefer subprocess.run() over Popen when you can.
Also, the argument to any subprocess should be either a single string with shell=True, or a list of strings (usually better, but needs the command to not use any shell feature, see also Actual meaning of shell=True in subprocess)
import subprocess

pass1 = "welcome1"
pass2 = "welcome2"

result = subprocess.run(
    ["sh", "test.sh"],
    input=f"{pass1}\n{pass2}\n",
    check=True,
    text=True,
    capture_output=True)
# stdout = result.stdout
# stderr = result.stderr

Demo: https://ideone.com/yNex6z
If you have timing issues, you'll need to revert to Popen, but use session.stdin.write rather than session.communicate.
Ultimately, if you have control over the tool you run in a subprocess, probably refactor it so that you can provide these values as command-line options instead, especially if reading from standard input is timing-sensitive. You generally want to avoid interactive I/O when automating workflows.

That is tough to do correctly - and that is the reason people are suggesting you change your code, instead of doing what you intend to.
It is possible to send and receive data interactively to a subprocess, but  the documentation and module focus in using the PIPE special value, and writing all the input at once followed by receiving all output at once. The .communicate method focus on that, as do the other answers here so far. The .communicate method doc read: "Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate ... " - so, it is a one time only call.
While the PIPE value will use o.s. pipes to to send and receive data, it is wrapped somehow that I could not actually write and read from the process in different iterations. Creating raw pipes with an os.pipe() call, however, works.
Pay attention for a long lived process, however, that the authors of the subprocess module went a great length to try to prevent a deadlock situation when the subprocess tries to write to its stdout:

Warning Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
.stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

That said, for a limited number of short messages, one can use raw pipes.
This is my "client" script - which could be your bash program:
ex2_driven.py :
while True:
    a = input()
    if a == "end":
        break
    print(a)

And here is how I could communicate with that in several rounds:
import os
from collections import namedtuple

Pipe = namedtuple("Pipe", "read_end write_end")
sender = Pipe(*os.pipe())
receiver = Pipe(*os.pipe())
Pipe = namedtuple("Pipe", "read_end write_end")
sender = Pipe(*os.pipe())
receiver = Pipe(*os.pipe())
proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "ex2_driven.py"], 
    stdin=sender.read_end, stdout=receiver.write_end)

os.write(sender.write_end, b"welcome 1\n")
print(os.read(receiver.read_end, 100))
os.write(sender.write_end, b"welcome 2\n")
print(os.read(receiver.read_end, 100))
os.write(sender.write_end, b"end\n")
proc.poll()
print(proc.returncode)

And this would print "welcome 1", "welcome 2" and "0" (the exit status).
Note that if you don´t need to read back from the child, just leave the default values for stdin and stderr, and then you can avoid the stall described in the docs in case the output PIPE of the child process gets full.
